# SignalR handshake timeout on IIS

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, iis-7, signalr, asp.net-core-2.1

**Environment:**

- IIS 7.0 on Windows 7 Home
- WebService written in asp.net core 2.1
- WebClient written in Angular
- Latest signalR library(.NET Core and JS)

**Issue:**

- Handshake request fails because of 15s timeout. The only response from server is `No Connection with that ID`. But sometimes it will connect in 4ms, which is completely strange(There is 10s delay between reconnections).

**Additional info:**

- IIS is also accessible from outside (let's say `www.myapp.domain.com:88/application`, signalr Hub: `www.myapp.domain.com:88/application/appHub` ) but it seems to be irrelevant because issue occurs also when I'm using only internal IPs.
- On IIS any other request works correctly and fast, the only issue is with signalR connections.
- Because of fallback it uses SSE.
- On development environment(kestrel) everything works fine.
- Every firewall etc. is turned off

**.Net Core:**

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowCredentials();
        }));
        services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
        {
            hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            hubOptions.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            hubOptions.HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        });
        services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new ProducesAttribute("application/json"));
            })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
            .AddControllersAsServices();
        services.AddAuthentication(Configuration);
        services.AddAuthorizationPolicies();

        return ServiceProviderFactory.CreateAutofacServiceProvider(services, Configuration);
    }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseExceptionHandler(env);
        app.UseWebSockets();
        app.UseHubs();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

**JS:**

```
private buildConnection() {
    const connectionBuilder = new HubConnectionBuilder();
    this.hubConnection = connectionBuilder
        .withUrl(environment.hubUrl, { accessTokenFactory: () => this.accessToken() })
        .configureLogging(LogLevel.Trace)
        .build();
}
```

(Sensitive data is erased)
[image]

Comment: any logs on the server?

Comment: have you tried `UseSignalR` instead of `UseWebsockets`?

Comment: Nothing interesting in logs to be honest. Today I tried configure it with IIS as reverse proxy - and still same issue. But if I connect directly to Kestrel it works. Also Using IIS 10 with websockets helps.